# "I broke it in[to] 'two pieces'/'half'"

Tags: prepositions

> 1.A Cut the onion in small pieces.
>
> 1.B Cut the onion into small pieces.
>
> 2.A I broke it in two pieces.
>
> 2.B I broke it into two pieces.
>
> 3.A I broke it in half.
>
> 3.B I broke it into half.

Is it obligatory to use "into" in all of the sentences above?

Comment: *It* isn't supposed to refer to *the onion*, is it?  I don't think you can *break an onion* (no instances on COCA or Google n-grams).

Comment: @snailplane It sounds sort of like recipe-talk to me. "Crack *an* egg over the bowl." "Sift *a* cup of flour." "Cut *an* onion." No?

Comment: I can cut an onion.  I just don't usually *break* my onions.  Where would I go to get them fixed?!

Comment: @snailplane Gah, I misread your comment.  I thought you were saying "Cut the onion" is right and "Cut an onion" isn't. *headdesk*  Silly me! But wait--you're telling me you've never been to Ye Olde Onion Fixery? I can give you the address on google maps ;)

Answer (score 4):

To *cut/break/chop/split/etc. X **into** Y* means you *started with X*, and *ended up with Y*.
Thus with "dividing" verbs, the end result *Y* should be plural (*two pieces*, for example).

For "joining" verbs, it's the other way around *(I joined several links into one long chain)*.

By the above principle, it should be perfectly reasonable to *break X **into halves***, but in fact we don't often say that - we usually use the more idiomatic form *break X **in half*** (or ***in two***).

I suspect that idiomatic use of **in** instead of **into** is at least partly influenced by the "awkward" repetition in forms like *cut X **into** two*. If you're *into* numbers, here are some interesting ones from Google Books:

> [cut it **in half**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20half%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20half%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...3296.4399.11.4660.4.4.0.0.0.0.87.220.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.cCK8sZdJkUQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *26,800 hits*
>    [cut it **in halves**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20halves%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20halves%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...121188.122544.12.123593.4.4.0.0.0.0.68.239.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.1iswI6KZ0t4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *1060*
>    [cut it **into half**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=dHr3D1LQ9qlL2x_CtqSg1w&ds=bo&pq=%22cut%20it%20in%20half%20and%22&cp=12&gs_id=ds&xhr=t&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20half%20and%22&es_nrs=true&pf=p&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20half%20and%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *77*
>    [cut it **into halves**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20halves%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20halves%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...31906.32802.15.34008.4.0.4.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.2p6xCDpo0zc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *641*
>
> [cut it **in** two](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...5385.5544.2.5998.2.2.0.0.0.0.44.87.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.TddcPK82Itg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *17,700*
>    [cut it **into** two](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20two%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20two%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...10217.11360.1.11862.4.4.0.0.0.0.69.193.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.6PvcTfxwyCg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *1370*
>    [cut it **in** three](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20three%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20three%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...301756.303050.3.303474.6.6.0.0.0.0.63.336.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.RBwqstMZMDA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *136*
>    [cut it **into** three](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20three%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20three%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...4734.5398.4.6074.2.2.0.0.0.0.76.119.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.ucPP80B6MZI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *235*
>    [cut it **in** four](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20four%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20four%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...3650.3802.19.4047.2.2.0.0.0.0.45.85.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.uY9S2DOHNIg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *233*
>    [cut it **into** four](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20four%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20four%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...4679.6983.18.7213.7.7.0.0.0.0.64.372.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.GQF6_BL4bok&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) *362*

(Note: I appended "and" to the search terms to reduce the number of irrelevant "false matches").

Also note that *two* itself is something of a special case, because we often don't bother following it by a noun such as *parts/pieces*. I won't bother giving all the numbers, but [cut it in six](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20six%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20six%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...59216.60371.39.60731.7.7.0.0.0.0.65.363.7.7.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.WojhYj-HY74&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) and [cut it in six pieces](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20in%20six%20pieces%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20in%20six%20pieces%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...5464.5615.38.5956.2.2.0.0.0.0.59.110.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.rgGCs-hBy18&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897) are vanishingly rare compared to the "standard" version [cut it **into** six pieces](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cut%20it%20in%20two%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22cut%20it%20into%20six%20pieces%20and%22&oq=%22cut%20it%20into%20six%20pieces%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...2989.5516.35.6586.8.8.0.0.0.0.80.454.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.qD65f4QZEg8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=24d56cf435ed9bed&biw=1318&bih=897).

---

I think what all that amounts to is that we usually use **into** in such contexts, but *two/half* represent "special cases" where we use **in** and don't always name the resultant parts. Other small numbers are affected by association with *two/half*, but this rapidly tails off when splitting into many more parts.

(Note: The "special status" of *half/two* arises peripherally in [this related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75153/split-in-vs-split-into)).

Answer (score -2):

the correct answers are:
1b

2b

3a

Comment: Hello, Mr. Gumpling!  I think perhaps the reason your answer was voted down is that you didn't *explain* why you chose to say 1b, 2b, and 3a.  If you'd like to do so, you can edit your answer to include an explanation of *why* you think these are the correct answers.  That way, the asker--and others--can learn how to solve this problem themselves in the future.